# Finding a solution of the equation $f(x)=x$ knowing that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le c|x - y|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le c|x - y|$$
for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and for a real constant $0 < c < 1$.

In addition, let $a_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ and
$$a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$$
for all $n > 1$.

We have to proof that $(a_n)$ is convergent and that it's limit $x_0$ is solution of the equation $f(x) = x$.

I have already shown that the sequence is convergent, since for all $n > 1$ we have that
$$|f(a_n) - f(a_{n-1})| = |a_{n + 1} - a_n| \le c|a_n - a_{n - 1}|,$$
which means that the sequence is contractive and therefore Cauchy.

However, I don't know how to proceed with the proof that $x_0 := \lim_{n} {a_n}$ is a solution of the equation $f(x) = x$ since in all my reasoning I assume that I can take the antiimage of $x_0$ and, even so, I do not get exactly what is requested.

I would appreciate any kind of idea to proceed with the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the condition $|f(x)-f(y)|\le c |x-y|$ it follows that $f$ is continuous. Since you already know that $a_n$ converges to some number $a$, say, this implies
$$f(a) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(a_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1} = a$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Perhaps it's a stupid question, but, how do you prove the continuity of 'f' from that hypothesis?

Comment: @MarioVagoMarzal Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then choose $\delta = \varepsilon$. If then $|x-y| < \delta$, you also have $|f(x)- f(y)| \le c|x-y| < c\delta = c\varepsilon < \varepsilon$. So $f$ is uniformly continuos.